# How to debug iOS subscriptions on Production Apple Servers from Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, in-app-purchase, in-app

I have a Xamarin Forms solution which uses subscriptions for both iOS and Android but this question is about iOS only. I have successfully verified my iOS subscriptions on the Apple Test Servers however, I would like to test against the Apple Production Servers from visual studio. When running my app with a non sandbox user account from my physical iOS device I receive the error "Cannot connect to the iTunes Store" on purchase. I think there maybe a constraint with running the App with the correct certificate and provisioning profile because you can't run an App through visual studio with distribution certificate and distribution provisioning profile.

Is the scenario of testing against production possible? If so, how this be achieved?

Comment: It's not possible to test against Apple production servers

Comment: The problem I'm having is when I release the App for App Review they come back with an error - "Cannot connect to itunes store" when they try to make a purchase.

Comment: It could be an issue with your product configuration in App Store Connect, they need to be in the 'Approved' state before you submit for review. Have you done that?